# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0^+}(\sin x)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $L=\lim _{x\to \:0+}\left(\sin \left(x\right)^x\right)$
Then we have:
$\log L = \lim _{x\to \:0+}\left(\sin \left(x\right)^x\right)$

$\log L = \lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\dfrac{\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x}}\right)$

$\log L = \lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\dfrac{\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)\right)}{\dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}}\right)$

$\log L = \lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\dfrac{x^{2\:}\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)\right)}{\sin x}\right)$

$\log L = \lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\dfrac{0.\:\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)\right)}{\sin x}\right)$ (as $x^2$ --> 0)

$\log L = \lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\dfrac{\ln \left(1\right)\:.\:\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)\right)}{\sin x}\right)$ (as ln(1)=0)

$\log L = \lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\dfrac{\:\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)+1\right)}{\sin x}\right)$

$\log L = ln(e) = 1$

i.e $L=e$

But my textbook holds L=1 as the solution as seen from [this graphic calculator](http://symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%2B%7D%28%5Csin%28x%29%5E%7Bx%7D%29/?origin=button)

Can anyone explain what I had done wrong in my method?

Comment: Errors are in obtaining this: $\lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\frac{0.\:\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)\right)}{sinx}\right)$ and this: $\lim \:_{x\to \:\:0+}\left(\frac{\:\ln \:\left(\sin \:\left(x\right)+1\right)}{sinx}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is

$$\ln a\cdot\ln b\ne \ln(a+b)$$

and there's another mistake: the transition from the fourth to fifth equality is wrong.

Comment: Oh yes omg silly me! All these time I didn't notice that.
Thanks Sami Ben. Btw Can you please explain why the transition from fourth to fifth equality is wrong. :/

Comment: If we look for a limit of $f(x)\times g(x)$ at $a$ where $f$ or $g$ are undefined on $a$ then it's wrong to write
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(a)g(x)$$

Comment: So you mean here $\lim \:_{x\to \:\:0}\left(\frac{ln\left(sin\left(x\right)\right)}{sin\left(x\right)}\right)$ is not defined

Comment: Yes it's undefined at $0$ so you can't replace $x^2$ by $0$. To understand this think at $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, can you replace $\sin x$ by $\sin0$?